# How does the flight controls performance differ in a compressible and in compressible environment?

Tags: aerodynamics, flight-controls

I know that in low speed flight compressibility effect is negligible and in high speed there will be an effect but how do they differ in flight controls such as primary and secondary?

Answer (score 4):

The main issue with compressibility related to flight controls, is the shift afterwards of the Aerodynamic Centre.

**Primary flight controls:** At subsonic speeds the AC is at about 25% chord, which shifts to about 50% aft at supersonic speeds. The aftward pressure shift starts before the aeroplane can make the sound barrier: many early aeroplanes became uncontrollable at transsonic speeds and crashed.

**Secondary flight controls:** The B737 has the most secondary flight controls of the aircraft I've worked with:

- Stab trim. The airplane trim shifts when entering transsonic flow, so the stab trim needs to be adjusted. Airplane certification makes sure that trim authority is sufficient even in a dive.
- Rudder trim. Same as above, but usually yaw trim is not large during all-engine flight.
- Throttle levers. I know of no effects of compressibility on the throttles.
- Nose wheel tiller. Not used in compressible flow.
- Trailing edge flaps. Not used in compressible flow.
- Leading edge flaps. Not used in compressible flow.
- Toebrakes. Not used in compressible flow.
- Spoilers. Not used in compressible flow.
- Landing gear levers. Not used in compressible flow.
- Fuel shut-off levers. Not used in compressible flow.
- Parking brake. Not used in compressible flow.

Comment: +1. Control reversal due to shock-induced separation could be added as a worst case scenario.